# What's with unexpected cancellation fees?

Tags: contract-law

I made a doctor's appointment by calling and reserving it.

I received a text messaging saying that I need to call the doctor's office and confirm my appointment, and that if I fail to do so the appointment may be cancelled.

I forgot about the appointment and missed it, and then I received a text message saying that I owe them $125 for failing to cancel the appointment.

Is this some kind of fraud? Or why do they do this?

I will never pay them unless ordered to do so by a court, which I don't expect to happen, but is it normal?

Comment: "I received a text messaging saying that I need to call the doctor's office and confirm my appointment..." - Did you confirm the appointment? Did you agree to some written terms at that time?

Comment: No I didn't confirm it and there's never been anything in writing

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for a business to charge for a skipped appointment is that by reserving a time slot, you have prevented them from seeing another patient, so they have suffered a financial loss. Your oral arrangement is sufficient: you don't need to sign an elaborate document to have a contract. It is unlikely that they will directly pursue you in court, instead they may just turn the matter over to a collection agency, which may or may not sue you. You could then dispute the charge in court.

Comment: Sue me for what? Exactly $125? Do you also believe that I could sue them for $125 if they were running late and unable to honor my appointment at exactly the right time?

Comment: Exactly $125. You'd be in a better position in suing them if they completely cancelled the appointment rather than just dealing with you in an untimely fashion. But you would have to show that you suffered a financial loss. There's no legal principle that favors doctors, so you could give it a try.

Comment: At what point did the OP agree to the $125 cancellation fee term? It was never communicated. Yes he did breach the contract by not visiting at agreed time but what now happens should be either negotiated or decided in court.